# Run JavaScript When New Images are Loaded

Tags: javascript

I did some research about this problem, but my situation is strange. I wrote a function to use ajax to get some image resource and stored it in a variable in js. window.onload() is working fine at the first time, which load all image to variable before displaying, but after that I clicked a link to load more pictures to that variable using ajax again, I do not know how to display those new ones ONLY when they are fully stored in that variable. Please help me with that.
Thanks, Dai.

Comment: your question title asks *"Run JavaScript Only After Entire Page Has Loaded"* however, you explained further and asked *"how to display those new ones ONLY when they are fully stored in that variable"*

Comment: Please show your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

The loading of individual images can be tracked with `img.onload`.  So, if you're loading a bunch of images and want to know when they are all loaded, you have to put onload handlers on all of them and accumulate a count for when they are all loaded.

```
var loadCnt = 0;
function cntLoads() {
    ++loadCnt;
    if (loadCnt > 20) {
        // all images loaded now, do whatever you want to do here
    }

}

var img1 = new Image();
img1.onload = cntLoads;
img1.src "xxxx";

var img2 = new Image();
img2.onload = cntLoads;
img2.src "yyyyy";

....
```

Comment: Thanks jfriend00, it really helps.